# Как изменить направление анимации в карусели bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, css3, bootstrap, css-animation

Есть модальное окно, в котором настроена карусель из двух слайдов. 
Когда с первого слайда уходишь на второй, то всё ок: второй появляется с правой стороны и "двигает" первый слайд. Но вот переход со второго слайда на первый при такой настройке выглядит нелогичным. Надо, чтобы первый слайд двигался с левой стороны. Можно это осуществить средствами css? и если надо скрипт писать, то на какие методы смотреть? 
Спасибо, кто откликнется, уже второй день голову ломаю... 
https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/199973/

```
        .carousel-item {
          transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
          transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7);
          &.active {
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть в файл _carousel.css бутстрапа, там есть следующие стили, которые надо правильно переопределить:

```
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
  transform: translateX(0);

  @supports (transform-style: preserve-3d) {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.carousel-item-next,
.active.carousel-item-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);

  @supports (transform-style: preserve-3d) {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.carousel-item-prev,
.active.carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);

  @supports (transform-style: preserve-3d) {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```